# Vue 3 + Vite build errors: paths of images and fonts not found

Tags: javascript, sass, vuejs3, vite

I have a web app made with Vue 3 + vite that is giving me problems with the building. The first thing that happens is that it can't find the images, so the solution has been to paste the images into the dist folder, although that's not the best solution. Mention I am using SASS and Bootstrap.

I should mention that if I put the images in the public folder, it does find them, but the path still giving error in the build.

The problem is that, all the paths, fonts, and images give an error (only on the build). I don't know how to organize the project so that this doesn't happen, in case it's that. I've been trying several things but without success. Any ideas or suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i do it all work

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />

-root
  |-public
    |-vite.svg
```

after `npm run build`

```
-root
  |-dist
    |-vite.svg
```

you should serve dist dir

example with http-server

```
npm install -g http-server
cd dist
http-server
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If I do it that way, everything is Ok. I pushed the dist folder to githug to test the web, but it is not working. I will try to figured out why. 

thanks again.

Comment: this blog can help
https://mkay11.medium.com/how-to-deploy-your-vite-vue-3-application-in-github-pages-2023-2b842f50576a